# How to achieve this behavior in Polars

Tags: python-polars

For my problem, I have to group data by "pulses". A pulse includes all data that occurs within a X period of time from the first element in the data. Then the next pulse starts at the next time after the previous pulse has ended. Here is a example of the desired behavior...

given the time data: 0, 3, 8, 15, 18, 24, 26, 28, 31, 56, 58, 62
and a period of 10.

The data should be split into 4 pulses. The first pulse starts at 0 and contains all data from 0-10. The next pulse starts at 15 (the next occurrence after the end of the last pulse 10) and goes to 25. This is then followed by pulse three which starts from 26 and contains all times from 26-36.  And lastly the final pulse starts at the next data point 56 and goes to 66.

Thus, you have...

pulse 1 (0-10): 0, 3, 8

pulse 2 (15-25): 15, 18, 24

pulse 3 (26-36): 26, 28, 31

pulse 4 (56-66): 56, 58, 62

[Behavior visualization Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEVvm.png)

input:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"time": [0.0, 3.0, 8.0, 15.0, 18.0, 24.0, 26.0, 28.0, 31.0, 56.0, 58.0, 62.0]})
```

desired output:

```
┌──────┬───────┐
│ time ┆ pulse │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0     │
│ 3.0  ┆ 0     │
│ 8.0  ┆ 0     │
│ 15.0 ┆ 1     │
│ 18.0 ┆ 1     │
│ 24.0 ┆ 1     │
│ 26.0 ┆ 2     │
│ 28.0 ┆ 2     │
│ 31.0 ┆ 2     │
│ 56.0 ┆ 3     │
│ 58.0 ┆ 3     │
│ 62.0 ┆ 3     │
└──────┴───────┘
```

I am struggling on how to effectively achieve this behavior without iteration as I need to be able to use the streaming API as I am testing on larger than memory CSV files. (However, if there is a way to avoid going over memory then I have a working cython version of this behavior)

I additionally previously looked into groupby_rolling as a solution but, I didnt know how to get the disjoint set of the groups created.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to fix the formatting of the visualization part.

Comment: yeah sorry. I included an image as a link with the proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to process the output of `.groupby_rolling()` to do this?

```
(df.with_columns(pl.col("time").set_sorted())
   .groupby_rolling(index_column="time", period="10i")
   .agg(pulse = "time")
)
```

```
shape: (12, 2)
┌──────┬──────────────────┐
│ time ┆ pulse            │
│ ---  ┆ ---              │
│ i64  ┆ list[i64]        │
╞══════╪══════════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ [0]              │
│ 3    ┆ [0, 3]           │
│ 8    ┆ [0, 3, 8]        │
│ 15   ┆ [8, 15]          │
│ 18   ┆ [15, 18]         │
│ 24   ┆ [15, 18, 24]     │
│ 26   ┆ [18, 24, 26]     │
│ 28   ┆ [24, 26, 28]     │
│ 31   ┆ [24, 26, 28, 31] │
│ 56   ┆ [56]             │
│ 58   ┆ [56, 58]         │
│ 62   ┆ [56, 58, 62]     │
└──────┴──────────────────┘
```

```
(df.with_columns(pl.col("time").set_sorted())
   .groupby_rolling(index_column="time", period="10i")
   .agg(pulse = "time")
   .with_columns(first = pl.col("pulse").list.first())
   .unique(subset="first", maintain_order=True, keep="last")
   .filter(
      (pl.col("pulse").list.lengths() <= pl.col("pulse").shift().list.lengths())
      .shift(-1)
      .fill_null(True)
   )
   .with_row_count("pulse_id")
   .explode("pulse")
   .unique("pulse", maintain_order=True)
   .select("pulse", "pulse_id")
)
```

```
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬──────────┐
│ pulse ┆ pulse_id │
│ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64   ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0        │
│ 3     ┆ 0        │
│ 8     ┆ 0        │
│ 15    ┆ 1        │
│ 18    ┆ 1        │
│ 24    ┆ 1        │
│ 26    ┆ 2        │
│ 28    ┆ 2        │
│ 31    ┆ 2        │
│ 56    ┆ 3        │
│ 58    ┆ 3        │
│ 62    ┆ 3        │
└───────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to preface that this kind of operation seems a little complex for Polars to be the right tool for it. However, this is my stab at the solution. First, let me create reproducible code:

```py
import polars as pl
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        "pulse": [0, 3, 8, 15, 18, 24, 26, 28, 31, 56, 58, 62]})
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("pulse").add(10).alias("end_pulse_at"))
)
```

As you may have imagined, the second column is just to help us figure out where the pulse should end. Next, we use the [`join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html) method, but just prior to that, we need all the columns we're using to be sorted:

```py
df_left  = df.sort("end_pulse_at")
df_right = df.sort("pulse")
```

Now, why did I create two DataFrame objects? Just because that's what Polars expects in that method's [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html). We're going to use this method to identify the *window*s for the pulse operations:

```py
windows = (
    df_left.join_asof(
        df_right, left_on="end_pulse_at", right_on="pulse", strategy="backward")
    .select("pulse", "pulse_right")
)
windows
```

produces a DataFrame with each row mapped to its *closest* row by value:

```py
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────┐
│ pulse ┆ pulse_right │
│ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ i64   ┆ i64         │
╞═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 8           │
│ 3     ┆ 8           │
│ 8     ┆ 18          │
│ 15    ┆ 24          │
│ …     ┆ …           │
│ 31    ┆ 31          │
│ 56    ┆ 62          │
│ 58    ┆ 62          │
│ 62    ┆ 62          │
└───────┴─────────────┘
```

We use this next to perform two additional joins: (1) an *anti*-join to filter out the rows where the *ending* pulse *also* has a matching value - we've already marked the *ending* pulse in our starting row. (2) is a simple *left* join to get the ending pulse value.

```py
print(
    df
    .join(windows, how="anti", right_on="pulse_right", left_on="pulse")
    .join(windows, how="left", on="pulse")
)
```

produces:

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│ pulse ┆ end_pulse_at ┆ pulse_right │
│ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---         │
│ i64   ┆ i64          ┆ i64         │
╞═══════╪══════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 10           ┆ 8           │
│ 3     ┆ 13           ┆ 8           │
│ 15    ┆ 25           ┆ 24          │
│ 26    ┆ 36           ┆ 31          │
│ 56    ┆ 66           ┆ 62          │
│ 58    ┆ 68           ┆ 62          │
└───────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

There's the problem of *multiple* matches, because Polars doesn't provide an option to change the "less than or equal to" match type to "less than" for the `strategy` argument. We can fix this using:

```py
print(
    df
    .join(windows, how="anti", right_on="pulse_right", left_on="pulse")
    .join(windows, how="left", on="pulse")
    .groupby("pulse_right", maintain_order=True)
    .first()
    .select("pulse", "pulse_right")
)
```

producing:

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────┐
│ pulse ┆ pulse_right │
│ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ i64   ┆ i64         │
╞═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 8           │
│ 15    ┆ 24          │
│ 26    ┆ 31          │
│ 56    ┆ 62          │
└───────┴─────────────┘
```

Which are the windows you were looking for.

## Edit

Additional details on the output expected were added after I answered this question. This is based on you keeping your ability to stream the operation in Polars. We rename the output before the edit as:

```py
correct_windows = (
    df
    .join(windows, how="anti", right_on="pulse_right", left_on="pulse")
    .join(windows, how="left", on="pulse")
    .groupby("pulse_right", maintain_order=True)
    .first()
    .select("pulse", "pulse_right")
)
```

And then create a function to return a series of `WhenThen` expressions:

```py
def whentheninator(df: pl.DataFrame):
    expr = pl.when(False).then(False)
    for row_idx, (start, end) in enumerate(df.iter_rows()):
        expr = (
            expr.when(
                pl.col("pulse").ge(start).and_(
                pl.col("pulse").le(end)))
            .then(row_idx)
        )
    return expr.alias("group")
```

Which can be called simply by:

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(whentheninator(correct_windows))
    .select("pulse", "group")
)
```

to produce:

```py
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ pulse ┆ group │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0     │
│ 3     ┆ 0     │
│ 8     ┆ 0     │
│ 15    ┆ 1     │
│ 18    ┆ 1     │
│ 24    ┆ 1     │
│ 26    ┆ 2     │
│ 28    ┆ 2     │
│ 31    ┆ 2     │
│ 56    ┆ 3     │
│ 58    ┆ 3     │
│ 62    ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

which is the output you requested.

Comment: See my answer that I posted simultaneous as you. I think you thought through yours a more than I did. :)

Comment: This is a tough one, yes. :D

Answer (score 0):

I finally remembered to use an asof join! Here we join on the nearest group, where a group is determined by the lower bound of "time".

```py
import polars as pl

df_input = pl.DataFrame({"time": [0.0, 3.0, 8.0, 15.0, 18.0, 24.0, 26.0, 28.0, 31.0, 56.0, 58.0, 62.0]})

df_desirable = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [0.0, 3.0, 8.0, 15.0, 18.0, 24.0, 26.0, 28.0, 31.0, 56.0, 58.0, 62.0],
        "group": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,],
    }
)

# Create groups where "time" contains the lower bound for the group
df_groups = pl.DataFrame({"group":[0,1,2,3], "time":[0., 15., 26., 56.]}).set_sorted("time")
# Use an asof join to join on the nearest group. We have to explicitly sort or say it is sorted so that the asof join knows it is sorted.
df_result = (
    df_input
    .set_sorted("time")
    .join_asof(df_groups, on="time", strategy="backward")
)

df_result.frame_equal(df_desirable) # True, they match!
```

Comment: This still requires knowing the start of each group in advance / calculating those points iteratively, which is the main crux of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that aspect of the requirements. You're totally right.